# View injection in Prism 4 and avoiding dependency

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Currently I'm in process of learning Prism. I'm building test application and I need to inject view into region on button click. I know how to do it using this code in view-model

```
IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TicketEditorRegion]; 
TicketEditorView view = _componentContainer.Resolve<TicketEditorView>();
region.Add(view);
```

Problem with this is that I need to add reference between modules. I assume this is not desirable thing.
I could avoid this by adding interface for some RegionBuilderThing and resolving it inside view-model with unity.

So is this a good approach and if it is, how to name this RegionBuilderThing (to follow some design pattern/guidance or something so others could understand it to)?
If this is not a good approach, what is?

Comment: You are definitely going to have to add the reference *somewhere*. Even if you have an `ITicketEditorView` then you need to instruct the container that it should resolve that to the concrete `TicketEditorView`. At that point you will need the reference.

Comment: Yes, but for that I have infrastructure project to which all modules have reference (it's used for common types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the foreign module containing the ViewModel you want to inject, create a class that subscribes to a particular EventAggregator event (say InjectChildEvent) and load it into your ComponentContainer as a singleton. the InjectChildEvent might take the RegionName as a parameter. In the subscription method, Resolve the ViewModel and inject it into the Region.

In the the main module, when the button is clicked, Publish an instance of the InjectChildEvent EventAggregator event.

This way you'll avoid having to have a reference to the other module. You will need to create the EventAggregator event in your Infrastructure project.

Comment: I found that this is called Controller in mvvm/prism applications. More information about it can be found here http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/15/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-3b-view-injection-and.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would inject inject a ViewModel into the IRegion's Views collection, not a View. Provided you have a DataTemplate in a loaded ResourceDictionary (App.xaml is as good as any), the ViewModel will be rendered as the appropriate View. In that way, you can completely separate your ViewModel code from any knowledge of whichever View(s) are used to render it on screen.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MyViewModel}">
    <views:MyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Apart from that , I don't think you need a RegionBuilder as such.

Comment: OK that is good but still I need to have reference to that view-model which is in module project (reference I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: Ok, if you're really firm on avoiding a reference to the other module, I've added another answer.